# FOSUserBundle 2.x + SonataUser = InvalidArgumentException

Tags: ajax, security, symfony, fosuserbundle, sonata-user-bundle

How do you fix [this](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataUserBundle/pull/271) error in your configuration?

I need SecurityHandler Support to make AJAX-login and registration forms in my Acme Bundle, so FUB 1.3 is useless for me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think there are still issues with SonataUser and FosUserBundle 2.x, see here: https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataUserBundle/issues/322